# Excel VBA select diagonal

Tags: vba, excel, select, diagonal

I have a question about using vba and select diagonal value.
For example:
[image: select diagonal]

I want to select diagonal value by using vba.
And the code I tried:

```
Sub SelectDiagonal()

a = Selection.Row()
b = Selection.Column()
c = Selection.Rows.Count
d = Selection.Columns.Count

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Cells(a + c - 1, b)

 For i = 1 To c - 1

  Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cells(a + c - 1 - i, b + i))

 Next
Rng.Select

End Sub
```

However, it did not work.
Any help? Thanks

[Edit] Sorry for my unclear explanation.
I know this code can work when I select the square `A1:D4`.
But, what I want is when I just select `A4` and execute code. It will automatically select the diagonal for me rather than selecting square before executing.

Comment: What doesn't work? It works for me if I select a square region on the sheet.

Comment: sorry for unclear explanation. I edited my question.

Comment: If you are always going to be selecting from column A and want to go diagonally up to the top then simply change to `c = Selection.Row()`. Note that you don't use d in the code so it isn't needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`CurrentRegion`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-currentregion-property-excel) and specify any cell in the square except you can't have data immediately adjacent to the square.

To quote from MSDN:

> Range.CurrentRegion:
>
> Returns a Range object that represents the current region. The current
>   region is a range bounded by any combination of blank rows and blank
>   columns.

So if you have data immediately adjacent to the square then the boundary is on the other side of the adjacent data, where the blank cells begin, and not at the end of the square.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectDiagonal()

Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Activesheet.Range("A4").CurrentRegion

Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, d As Long, i As Long

a = myRange.Row()
b = myRange.Column()
c = myRange.Rows.Count
d = myRange.Columns.Count

Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Cells(a + c - 1, b)

 For i = 1 To c - 1

  Set Rng = Union(Rng, Cells(a + c - 1 - i, b + i))

 Next
Rng.Select

End Sub
```

I wouldn't normally advocate using [`UsedRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-usedrange-property-excel) but, you can here, if your data is set up as shown. It will fall over if there is other data in the sheet.

To quote again from MSDN:

> Worksheet.UsedRange Property (Excel)
>
> Returns a Range object that represents the used range on the specified
>   worksheet

So, for example, if cell `I7` also had data then the `Activesheet.UsedRange.Address` would become `$A$1:$I$7` not `$A$1:$E$5`.

Simply use this line instead in the code above

```
Set myRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

There are lots of other ways to essentially define the range (`myRange`) to work with including finding the last row, last column or last cell and using that in defining the range to work with.  Ron De Bruin does a great piece on this [Find last row, column or last cell](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

I think `CurrentRegion` is quite simple in this instance. The solution you choose will be determined by the layout of your data.